Constant power laser driver circuit design
I am working on project for which I have to design a constant power laser diode driving circuit. I came across another post which explored a similar problem. Reading further I found these circuits from ROHM.

How do these circuits work?
What is the voltage across the laser diode? How can I control it?
Is this circuit somehow limiting the current?  I would like to modify it for my laser diode.

As far as I understand, the voltage across the laser diode in the circuits by ROHM for the M-type LD will be equal to Vd = VCC-Vdrop(from transistor)-Vr1. Similarly the current will also be limited by only R1 and controlled by the transistor. Is this correct?
Moreover, I would like to know more about other types of circuits that I can make that can control the output power of the laser diode. Any references/books/tutorials regarding it would be appreciated.
Edit: I also found this circuit while searching. Is this circuit somehow better than the ones by ROHM?


How are these circuits working?

Apart from the first circuit (which doesn't use a photodiode to detect laser output light level), the remaining circuits maintain constant laser light output by actually using a photodiode. The document then shows different circuits (all based on using photodiode feedback) that suit different laser-photodiode wiring configurations. The circuits work by limiting/maintaining the laser diode current once the photodiode is producing an output level that corresponds with the required laser light output. It's a negative feedback system.

What is the voltage across the laser diode? How can I control it?

It's irrelevant because the "good" circuits use photodiode feedback and, this automatically adjusts laser current (and terminal voltage as a result) to maintain constant light power at the value required (as set by the 5 kΩ potentiometer). Note that R3 is used to "calibrate" the photodiode.

Is this circuit somehow limiting the current? As I would like to
modify it for my laser diode.

Any of the circuits shown that use photodiode feedback are suitable for your laser diode because, your laser diode has an electrically uncommitted photodiode on pins 4 and 5. You should use it because, that's what it's intended to do. When you buy your photodiode you may have a calibration figure that comes with the specific photodiode that tells you exactly what output it produces for a given laser light output but, you may also have to self-calibrate using a light meter.

I also found this circuit while searching. Is this circuit somehow
better than the ones by ROHM?

I prefer that circuit because that's very similar to ones I have used for laser control but, I'm sure that the ROHM circuit have equal performance in many areas and possible better performance in others. The trick here is to use a simulator and figure what what best suits your needs.


How are these circuits working?

If you regulate the current, the power is also regulated. The problem is the scale varies with the laser diode, and will change with temperature and other parameters, so if you need a calibrated value for power you'll need to measure the power with a photodiode. Another thing you could do is temperature control the laser diode module.

What is the voltage across the laser diode? How can I control it?

Diodes have an exponential I-V Curve, typically current control is used because the voltage is more sensitive to noise. Any kind of current limiter circuit can be used. If the current is controlled so will the voltage.

Voltage is also sensitive to temperature variation. A good operating voltage at one temperature might blow up the laser if the temperature changes by 10 degrees.
